# Length of stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried creating a SQL Server project and named a procedure

```
psp_insert_new_customer_insurance_policy_answer
```

After building, I get this error:

> Error 3 SQL00103: The identifier that starts with 'insert_new_customer_insurance_policy_answers' is too long. Maximum length is 32.   C:~stored_procedures\insert\psp_insert_new_customer_insurance_policy_answer.sql 23  1   smartinsuredb

The logs are below

```
Creating [dbo].[psp_update_existing_claim_answer]...
Creating [dbo].[psp_update_existing_claim_status]...
Creating [dbo].[psp_update_existing_company]...
Creating [dbo].[psp_update_existing_country]...
Creating [dbo].[psp_update_existing_customer_insurance_policies]...
(2065,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 103, Level 15, State 2, Procedure psp_update_existing_customer_insurance_policies, Line 23 
The identifier that starts with update_existing_customer_insurance_policies' is too long. Maximum length is 32.
```

> (2078,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 103, Level 15, State 2, >Procedure psp_update_existing_customer_insurance_policies, Line 36 The identifier that starts with 'update_existing_customer_insurance_policies' is too long. Maximum length is 32.
>   An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

I have searched this on google and found no solution

The question is how can I name a stored procedure more than 32 characters?

Comment: Maximum length for stored procedures and functions name is 128.

Comment: You can name upto 128 charcters. I don't think problem is with the name

Comment: Are you sure this is Microsoft SQL Server? As already mentioned the max length for object names is 128, and that error doesn't look familiar.

Comment: When googling `Error 3 SQL00103:` a bunch of Oracle related stuff comes up.  Are you really using SQL Server?

Comment: yes, sure. It is Visual Studio I am using

Comment: Not sure how that proves you're not using Oracle - [Visual Studio can connect to platforms other than SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/07/18/connecting-to-oracle-from-visual-studio.aspx).

Comment: (That doesn't mean that makes sense - Oracle stored procedure names are limited to 30 characters, not 32. And the error message itself, starting with `Msg 103`, definitely feels like SQL Server. But SQL Server procedure names are limited to 128 characters, not 32. Perhaps you should post the actual code of the stored procedure.)

Answer (score 0):

My Mistake, It was name of transaction, not the name of procedure...Thanks everyone